# Как добавить Windows (не UWP) как платформу для Facebook приложения?

Tags: facebook-api, microsoft-store

Пишу программу для Windows, которая использует Facebook Api. Мне нужно получить токен пользователя с нужными правами (что я и делаю, но пока только для тестового аккаунта). Чтобы получить возможность запросить эти права у всех пользователей необходимо отправить заявку на проверку, а для этого нужно указать платформу:
[image]

Если выбрать Windows, то нужно указать данные от Windows Store, которых у меня нет, т.к. моё приложение никак не связано с этим магазином.

Какую платформу указать?

Comment: вам нужен именно "Приложения на Windows", остальные варианты технически не подойдут. Проблем-то нет создать девелоперский аккаунт Windows Store.

Comment: Для web им нужна ссылка на сайт для проверки, может быть и для WinStore понадобится? Выложить в WinStore не UWP приложение будет проблематично.